# Where do I store pre-compiled binaries?

Tags: software-installation

Since pre-compiled binaries are just portable files: what's the proper place to manually store them without making my system a mess?

Comment: Welcome to UNIX stackexchange. You traditionally store manually installed binaries in `/opt` (optional add-ons dir).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual places are `/usr/local` or `/opt` for bigger complete applications.

I put all my self-compiled applications into `/usr/local/stow/application_name`, using `make install` or some similar command to copy the whole hierachy.

Then use `stow` on them to manage symlinks. The advantage is that all paths (binary, library) work out of the box, and the applications are well separated, and I can remove them easily again.

That's also where I'd put pre-compiled binaries, into a `bin` subdirectory of `application_name`.

> Since pre-compiled binaries are just portable files

I don't know what you mean. Pre-compiled binaries are very much **not** portable, it depends on which architecture they were compiled for. You also don't know which librarie versions they were compiled for. These libraries may not exist on your system in that version.

---

For your Pomotroid example, here is what I would do if I wanted to use this on my computer:

1. They have a `.deb` package, and I use a Debian-derived distro, so I'd just download this and install it on my system.
2. The next variant would be to clone the repository under `/usr/local/src/pomotroid`, run the build in this one, modify the installation process to use `/usr/local/stow/pomotroid`, run the installation process, then use `stow`. This is how I deal with the majority of self-compiled software on my system.
3. The third variant would be to add an `rpm` package build process to the repository, make a pull request, and have the release `rpm` packages for me in the future (and for everyone else who needs an `rpm` package)
4. The fourth variant would be to get the distributed tar-file, unpack it in something like `/usr/local/app/pomotroid` (`/opt/app/pomotroid` is also fine), then write a script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before it executes whatever the main program is in there (never tried to install an electron app before).

The tar file includes quite a few dynamic libraries which I also have on my system in probably different versions, so I really don't just want those to appear in the default library path for other programs to pick up - this could seriously mess up my system.

If I wanted to update to the newest version of this on a regular basis, I'd either start scripting the installation process, or invest some time to get an `rpm` package built.

Comment: You're talking about putting the whole binaries folder under `/usr/local`, `/opt` & `/usr/local/stow/`. Right?

What's the correct way to do it? Just using `cp` or `mv`?

Comment: When using stow, do I have to worry about copying these folders to `/usr/..` before?

Comment: What I meant by portable: I saw in another question someone saying that binaries are portable because you don't have to setup stuff, like in source code. All you have to do is execute the binary.

Comment: You see...

I'm using Fedora 32 and when I install an application using _.rpm_ files, the system seems to be aware of the application, in a way that I can see the app icon in Wayland menu and execute the it using terminal (without the need to create an `.bashrc` alias).

Would stow allow me to achieve this same setup?

Comment: No. I am talking about this: I have application X with binaries X1 and X2. I put those under `/usr/local/stow/X/bin/X1` and `.../X2`, and then use stow to make symlinks. The same for application Y with binaries Y1, Y2, and Y3. Now when I want to remove application X, it's easy. Edited answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I have no idea what Wayland does. "App icon" suggests it's not **only** a binary, but at least another file for the app icon... And if Wayland is set up to look for those in the same way in `/usr/local` as it does in `/usr`, then yes, that should also work. Provided you install the icon together with the binary ...

Comment: @sprangboogieman No, `stow` is not meant for that. The task you describe cannot be done by simply placing the binaries in "the usual directories" (so to say). Copying a binary to these locations will let you run it from the console without typing the absolute filepath, but creating icons in menus etc. requires post-installation steps usually performed by the software package manager of your OS. You can do the necessary steps also by hand (details will depend on your desktop environment), but for deployment to different machines, you'll need to create an actual RPM package.

Comment: I was referring to the _linux.tar.gz_ release of this repo: https://github.com/Splode/pomotroid/releases

Comment: To achive my goal I had to: extract it to `~/.local/share/pomotroid` and create a symlink for its executable file in `~/.local/bin`. After that, I made a _.desktop_ file by hand in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: I'm assuming I correctly did all the work a package like _.rpm_ would do automatically. Although, I'm not sure about the folder part. Should I really put this kind of release in `/opt`?

Comment: Should I really be doing this by hand for similar application releases or there's some way to automate it?

Comment: To start with: You should edit your question and more clearly state what you are trying to do, and you should have had the pomotroid example in the question right from the start. See edit in answer for rest.